# HTML banner that extends forever

Tags: html, css, header

I have a header inside a container div with a width of 960px. The header holds a couple logos perfectly centered on the page. I'm suppose to have a background gradient that extends forever behind the header. The problem arises because the gradient banner is limited by the width of the 960px. I tried moving the banner out of the 960px container and positioning it down but it leaves unwanted space above the header.

I've tried z-index -2. Nothing.

Any suggestions

Comment: When should I accept an answer when the answer is wrong? where is the ANSWER IS WRONG checkmark?

Comment: #header {
    height:175px;  background-repeat:repeat;
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top , #0f5979, #000);  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#006699), to(#003366));
} the above code is nested inside this div:.container_12 .grid_12,
.container_16 .grid_16 {
  width: 940px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 1background-repeat1 CSS property for this.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-repeat